# swagger 2 with JAXB generated classes

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have JAXB generated classes

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MyResponse", propOrder = {
    "member1",
    "member2",
    "member3"
})
public class MyResponse implements Serializable {
<... other class members; setters/ getters ...>
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "myRequest", propOrder = {
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
})
public class MyRequest implements Serializable {
    <... other class members; setters/ getters ...>
}
```

However, swagger 2 (version 3.0.0) generates example values as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<JAXBElement«MyRequest»>
    <name>
        <localPart>jhgkhgk</localPart>
        <namespaceURI>gfjgfj</namespaceURI>
        <prefix>gfjhgfj</prefix>
    </name>
    <nil>true</nil>
    <MyRequest>
        <test1>string</test1>
        <test2>string</test2>
        <test3>string</test3>
    </MyRequest>
</JAXBElement«MyRequest»>
```

How to force swagger to generate example values of

```
<MyRequest>
    <test1>string</test1>
    <test2>string</test2>
    <test3>string</test3>
</MyRequest>
```

My Controller class

```
public @ResponseBody JAXBElement<MyRequest> test(
        @RequestBody JAXBElement<MyResponse> message) {
```

}

Update no.1

Just find out that putting

```
@ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(
                name = "message",
                dataTypeClass = MyResponse.class,
                examples = @io.swagger.annotations.Example(
                        value = {
                                @ExampleProperty(value = "{'property': 'test'}", mediaType = "application/xml")
                        }))
})
```

on top of my controller gives 1/2 of required result, now need to figure on
how to add namespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution - abandon SpringFox and use springdoc-openapi-ui instead (if you are
a java developer) it is drop dead easy, i.e

```
@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody(content = @Content(examples = {
                   @ExampleObject(
                           name = "Person sample",
                           summary = "person example",
                           value ="my custom example to be executed")}))
```